Spotify API 403 Forbidden Error When Adding Tracks to Playlist Despite Correct Token and Scopes
I'm experiencing a 403 Forbidden error when trying to add a track to a Spotify playlist using the Spotify Web API. Despite having a correctly configured token and permissions, I’m still facing this issue.
Details:

Spotify Client ID: My client ID
Spotify Client Secret: Client Secrete
Redirect URI: http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback

Access Token Details:
{
  "access_token": "my access token",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "my refresh token",
  "scope": "playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative",
  "expires_at": 1725396428
}


Error Log:
INFO 2024-09-03 20:16:02,097 cron Distributing 1 playlists to job scheduled at 2024-09-03 20:47:02.097874 for Order ID 28.
INFO 2024-09-03 20:16:02,100 cron Adding track 0TT2Tzi8mEETCqYZ1ffiHh to playlist 4CeTjVTCZOFzTBdO8yaLvG
ERROR 2024-09-03 20:16:02,557 cron Spotify API error: https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/4CeTjVTCZOFzTBdO8yaLvG/tracks:
 Check settings on developer.spotify.com/dashboard, the user may not be registered.
ERROR 2024-09-03 20:16:02,558 cron Check if the user 31rizduwj674dch67g22bjqy7sue is correctly registered and has permissions to modify the playlist.

What I’ve Tried
1- Verified Token Scopes:
The token includes scopes playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative.
2- Checked Token Validity:
The token is valid and has not expired. I also attempted to refresh it.
3- Confirmed Playlist Ownership:
Ensured that the playlist is either owned by or shared with the user whose token is being used.
4- Re-authenticated:
Re-authenticated and re-authorized the application to confirm there are no issues with authentication.
5- API Endpoint & Request Format:
Verified that the API endpoint and request format conform to the Spotify API documentation.
6- User Permissions:
Confirmed that the user has the necessary permissions to modify the playlist.
Questions
1- Is there any additional configuration or setting I might be missing on the Spotify Developer Dashboard?
2- Could the issue be related to specific permissions or configurations for the playlist or user account?
3- Are there other common issues or troubleshooting steps for resolving 403 Forbidden errors with the Spotify API?
Environment Details:

Django latest
Spotipy for Spotify OAuth
Python 3.12
Ubuntu 22.04

Request sample - Curl:
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/6QoiIukPdZNHILKt4S7SDF/tracks?uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A0TT2Tzi8mEETCqYZ1ffiHh' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer 1POdFZRZbvb...qqillRxMr2z' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "uris": [
        "spotify:track:0TT2Tzi8mEETCqYZ1ffiHh"
    ],
    "position": 0
}'

Any assistance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Can you provide the request you're sending to spotify as a curl statement?

Bill, I have updated my question you can get the curl statement from there

Thanks! That's helpful. Try changing "Bearer " to "Basic ".

Didn't work. I believe it's not a problem with Bearer
